# How can a button visible only on given month and date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want a button to be visible only at given date and month otherwise want to hide it. Also want to make the button disable after first click. How can I do this? I have tried following code but it didn't help me.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function today()
        {
        var currentTime = new Date()
        var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
        var day = currentTime.getDate()
        var d = new Date();
        var curr_hour = d.getHours();
        var curr_min = d.getMinutes();


    if(month==1 && day==1)
{ 
document.getElementById('xx').style.visibility='visible';
}
else
{
document.getElementById('xx').style.visibility='hidden';
}
}
</script>
```

Html:

```
<form method=post action="update_registration.jsp" name="form1">
<input type="image" SRC="/Patankar/PNH/images/click_anim.gif"   id="xx"  onClick='today();' ALT="Submit Form" style="visibility:hidden;display:none" >
</form>
```

Comment: If i was you I would do the work in the backend to save putting somethign on the page which a person could hack and have access to.

Comment: You call this method after you have clicked the button. So you hide it after you have used it. Try calling it in the onload of the body element.

Comment: Your input has 2 id's? That's not a very good policy

Answer (score 1):

Please choose only one display style like visible XOR display.
Then

```
window.onload = function() {

    // you manipulation with date wich set varibale canClick to true if all ok or to false otherwise 

    if (canClick)
    {
       var button = document.getElementById('xx');
      button.style.display = 'block'; //if you choose visibility - button.style.visibility= 'visible';
      button.onclick = function() {this.disabled = false}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use document.getElementById('xx').style.display='none'; 
or document.getElementById('xx').style.display='block';

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend using jQuery for any Javascripting as it makes it compatible across all major browsers. Then you can do the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var now = new DateTime();
        var month = 1;
        var day = 1;
        if(now.Month == month && now.Day == day)
        {
            $('#itemToHide').css('display', 'visible');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#itemToHide').css('display', 'hidden');
        }
        $('#itemToHide').click(function () {
            $(this).css('display','hidden');
            $(this).attr('disabled','true');
        }  
    });
</script>
```

If you put this into the  section of your code, give the button you want to hide an id attribute and change the itemToHide in the script above to whatever ID you give to the element

EDIT: You will also need to remove the **display:none** style from the button.

EDIT: Just added code for hiding it on click.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want disable button after first click it should be like this (using jQuery):

```
 $('#xx').click(function(){
     $(this).attr('disabled','true');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById('abc').style.visibility='hidden';
    }, (new Date(new Date().toDateString())-  new Date(2011, 7, 19) 
/* the date on which button should be hidden*/))
```

This code will hide button even if page is left open from previous day to the date button should  not be visible. Modify the code to reverse the effect.

Answer (score 0):

No jquery needed

whatch this demo it works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/enWEM/

In you input you have 2 visibility options (visible and display) use only one

Next you must run the javascript code that is also missing

Comment: @samiksha don't forget to choose the right answer and upvote anyone that provided useful information

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really perfect first remove any one id attribute in your input element, you have written two ids which may be confusing the script,

```
<input type="image" SRC="/Patankar/PNH/images/click_anim.gif"   id="xx"  id="return1" onClick='today();' ALT="Submit Form" style="visibility:hidden;display:none" >

id="xx"  id="return1"
```

Remove any one and change accordingly in your script and further use display instead of visibility and to disable the button use,

```
document.getElementById("xx").disabled=true;
```

Hope this should work.

Regards,
Karthik